# Авторизация на сайте с помощью API ВКонтакте?

Tags: vkontakte-api, авторизация

Здравствуйте!

На сайте поиска недвижимости имеются фильтры поиска (цена, метраж и т.п.). Необходимо дать возможность пользователю сохранять свои фильтры и получать оповещения в ВКонтакте посредством отправки информации о новых квартирах в личные сообщения.

Однако, не совсем понятно, каким образом это реализовать. Можно было бы создать приложение. Осуществляя авторизацию на сайте с помощью ВКонтакте по протоколу OAuth, получить от пользователя разрешение отправлять ему личные сообщения. А в базу данных занести необходимые для дальнейшей работы данные: id пользователя и желаемые фильтры.

Непонятно, как затем пользователю поменять фильтры.

Возможно, просить пользователя вновь авторизоваться, считать его фильтры и вывести ему их? Я верно рассуждаю? Может быть есть какие-нибудь другие варианты реализации?

На coursera есть возможность зарегистрироваться на сайте с помощью facebook.

Прошу подсказать. Заранее благодарен!

**upd**. Сайт не имеет аккаунтов пользователей.

Comment: Какого рода приложение Вы предполагаете создать? Отдельный сайт или мобильное? На мой взгляд, это излишне, если уже имеется тот сайт недвижимости. И в чём трудности с изменением фильтров? В окне настроек можно просто сделать форму для этого, и совсем не трудно разделить её с запросом доступа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно учесть, что у Вк есть несколько видов доступов сторонних приложений к АПИ: от имени пользователя / сообщества / приложения (["Получение ключа доступа"](https://vk.com/dev/access_token)). У них разные ограничения и способы получения. Отправка сообщений (метод [messages.send](https://vk.com/dev/messages.send)) доступна только для первых двух.

Подразумевается, что **ключ доступа пользователя** будет иметь полный доступ (включая возможность отправки сообщений) только у приложения-клиента, которое выполняет действия не автоматически, а по указанию пользователя, онлайн. То есть, для отправки сообщений подходит только [*Implicit flow*](https://vk.com/dev/implicit_flow_user), серверный *Authorization code flow* нет. Однако, если все действия будут производиться лишь с одной страницы, то получить ключ доступа пользователя можно вручную, а потом явно прописать в код.

Альтернативное и более качественное решение – получение **ключа доступа сообщества** и отправка нужных сообщений от имени группы/публичной страницы. Для этого вполне подходит [*Authorization code flow*](https://vk.com/dev/authcode_flow_group).

### Как это должно выглядеть в целом?

В обоих вышеописанных случаях Вашим пользователям достаточно будет указать свою страницу, никаких прав давать не надо (что и логично, Вам же не нужно совершать действий *на его странице, от его имени*). На Вашем сайте будет раздел со ссылкой на страницу пользователя и редактором интересующих его фильтров; всё это он может в любой момент отредактировать.

Также Вам понадобится автоматически выполняющийся код (используя, [например, cron](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)), который будет проходить по имеющимся в базе данных сведениях о пользователях с настройками по Вк, формировать для них материалы и отправлять на основе идей выше.

### Update.

Если на Вашем сайте нет аккаунтов, страницы настроек, то можно сделать так:

1. Создать аккаунты и с настройками. Вероятно, это будет полезно не только для данной задачи.
2. Но можно придумать и более легковесное решение. Например, при вводе пользователем данных в первый раз (то есть, его страницы Вк нет в БД) генерировать пароль, который вместе с новостями отправлять ему в ЛС. А при попытке изменений данных для уже существующего в БД пользователя просто запрашивать этот пароль. Можно даже поступить ещё интереснее и отправлять в ЛС не пароль, а уникальную ссылку, в которой его пароль содержится, тогда при изменении подписки пароль вводить не нужно, он будет вписан на странице каким-нибудь `<input type="hidden">`.

Comment: Каким образом ограничить доступ на страницу пользователя на сайте, чтобы только пользователь имел к ней доступ?

Comment: @АльбертАлександров Так у вас нет аккаунтов, страницы настроек?

Comment: Нет. Если бы были, то не уточнял бы здесь.

Comment: @АльбертАлександров конечно, но столь важную информацию стоило бы уточнить ещё в вопросе. Дополнил ответ парой вариантов.

Comment: Да, виноват. Обновил.

Comment: Может сделать так, как описано здесь https://roothelp.ru/lessons/kak_uznati_id_polizovatelu_vkontakte_zashedshego_na_sait?

Предположим, пользователь впервые оказался на сайте. Делает свои, и в какой-то момент решил сохранить фильтр. Пользователь увидел кнопку "Сохранить фильтр" и нажал на нее. Появилось окошко-предупреждение от ВКонтакте, что сайт хочет получить доступ к персональным данным. user соглашается. id пользователя и фильтры сохраняются в БД.

При последующих посещениях сайт уже узнает пользователя и просто обновляет информацию в БД.

Comment: @АльбертАлександров это решение для выявления пользователей тоже вполне приемлемое.

Comment: спасибо за подсказки

Comment: @АльбертАлександров благодарности на этом сайте показывают в виде стрелочек вверх и галочки принятого ответа `:)`

Comment: Да, само собой)